# How to perform an action on the result of a mono which meets a filter condition

Tags: java, rx-java, project-reactor

I'm messing around with Mono from the reactor library: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html

I want to run an operation, in this case mutate testObject to contain test, which will only be true if a condition is met. I'm trying to do this using .filter but I cant get it to do exactly what I want. I do not want the result to be of the mono to be modified, I want doOnNext to run something which has no effect on the underlying data models.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

/**
 * @author Doctor Parameter
 */
public class FilterTest {

    @Test
    public void test(){

        String test = "test";
        AtomicReference<String> testObject = new AtomicReference<>();

        //The filter is true
        testObject.set(null);
        String filterTrue = Mono.just(test)
                .filter(string -> string.equals(test))
                .doOnNext(string -> testObject.set(string))
                .block();
        Assert.assertEquals(test, testObject.get());
        Assert.assertEquals(test, filterTrue);

        //The filter is false
        testObject.set(null);
        String filterFalse = Mono.just(test)
                .filter(string -> string.equals("Something Else"))
                .doOnNext(string -> testObject.set(string))
                .block();
        Assert.assertEquals(null, testObject.get());
        Assert.assertEquals(test, filterFalse); //This fails, filterFalse == null

        //I can't do this, I don't have a reference to test in the real code. A valid answer can be how to get a reference within the Mono. 
        testObject.set(null);
        String filterFalse = Mono.just(test)
                .filter(string -> string.equals("Something Else"))
                .doOnNext(string -> testObject.set(string))
                .thenReturn(test)
                .block();
        Assert.assertEquals(null, testObject.get());
        Assert.assertEquals(test, filterFalse); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The why do you use `filter`? And what do the first code blocks contribute to the question?

Comment: @abetteroliver the first block is the true case where the filter will set the testObject, the second is the negative case where the filter will not set the testObject.

Comment: I understand that, but my point is that the _"false"_ block would have been enough to illustrate the problem. The accepted answer builds on my first question and I still would like to understand the reasoning behind using `filter`. The condition belongs to the side effect, not to the stream, so `doOnNext` is the natural place for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't use `filter` at all, which eliminates the data from the overall sequence whenever the filter doesn't match. Keep the entire side-effecting logic within `doOnNext`:

```
    //The filter is false
    testObject.set(null);
    String filterFalse = Mono.just(test)
            .doOnNext(string -> {
              if (string.equals("Something Else"))
                  testObject.set(string);
             })   
            .block();
    Assert.assertEquals(null, testObject.get());
    Assert.assertEquals(test, filterFalse);
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using compose:

```
String filterTrue = Mono.just(test)
    .compose(string -> string
        .filter(filterString -> filterString.equals(test))
        .doOnNext(nextString -> testObject.set(nextString))
        .then(string)
    ).block();
Assert.assertEquals(test, testObject.get());
Assert.assertEquals(test, filterTrue);
```